# Angular2 router 3 levels of menu

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have 3 levels of menu

MainMenu

--SecondaryMenu

----SubMenu

These are different components inside different modules. Each component has
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

It's ok when I click on item of SecondaryMenu. I see all 3 levels of menu. But when I click on SubMenu item, SecondaryMenu disappears. SubMenu replaces SecondaryMenu router-outlet.

Why SubMenu item goes to parent's router-outlet?

My code (shortened):
secondary.component.html

```
<div class="panel">
  <ul class="tab-items">
    <li class="tab-item" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="link" routerLink="/secondary/topics">
            <span>{{ 'Topics' | i18n }}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

secondary.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "secondary", component: SecondaryComponent, children: [
    { path: "secondary", redirectTo: "/secondary/topics"},
    { path: "topics", component: TopicsComponent},
]
}
];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SecondaryRoutingModule {
```

Submenu.component.html

```
<div class="panel">
<ul class="tab-items">
    <li class="tab-item" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="link" routerLink="/routing/input-points/script">
            <span>{{ 'WCScript' | i18n }}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>
```

Submenu.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "secondary/topics", component: TopicsComponent, children: [
    {path: "secondary/topics", redirectTo: "/secondary/topics/script"},
    { path: "script", component: WebScriptComponent} }
]
}
];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SubmenuRoutingModule {
```

**UPDATE**
This helps, but submenu components should know that they are inside SecondaryComponent:

```
path: "secondary", component: SecondaryComponent, children: [
    { path: "topics", component: TopicsComponent, children: [
        { path: "script", component: WebScriptComponent},
```

How to avoid it?

Comment: It should not be. I am not sure, How you are trying. Can you add your code?

Comment: @AvneshShakya I've added some code, could you see, please? Thanks!